# Left margin of post image

Tags: css, image, margins

Using inspector I can see that the left margin of my post image is set to 25%.
I would like to change it to 0% so it is in align with text but am having no luck with any of the codes I have tried and can not find it in the CSS

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Prior to continuing your journey here, please take some time to visit the 'how to ask' section here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sara please post an example so we can see whats going on or create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

1) In the inspector, there should be a line where it shows a location of the code (file name and a line). There you can edit the code.

Now for the hacks...
2)If you still can't find it, just override it in your stylesheet. Put

```
margin-left:0;
```

at the very bottom of it.
3)If that doesn't help- try adding !important

```
margin-left:0 !important;
```

4)If that doesn't help and your style is somewhere else put the following code right before the head closing tag

```
<style>
   .yourelementclass {margin-left:0;}
</style>
```

If that doesn't work- try adding !important once again.

Or it could also be some javascript setting style.
So, right before closing body add a jquery script.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".yourelementclass").css('margin-left','0');
    });
</script>
```

That would be a few things, one of which, most likely is going to solve the problem. All of it is hacky, but that's the best I can do without actual code or link